Proper value for com.apple.quarantine on 14.4.1
I’m running into an issue on macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 relating to file quarantine
xattr -w com.apple.quarantine true uTorrent\ Web

When I write quarantine metadata to a this file, it results in utorrent not being able to open.
Im looking for the proper value for com.apple.quarantine say for a file you've pulled using curl. Assuming that's of any value.
Is there a way to run a newly downloaded binary by gatekeeper?

Remove the attribute.
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine filnametoremovetheattributefrom

